# What do square brackets before a number mean in Java? e.g. []89 or [1, 2, 3]89

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and haven't been able to find any explanations on what the syntax such as [1, 2, 3, 4]5 means.

```
import java.util.*;

class SumDigPower {

    static List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
    public static List<Long> sumDigPow(long a, long b) {
      for(long i = a; i<=b; i++) {
        if(isEureka(i)) {
          list.add(i);
        }
      }

      return list;
    }


    public static boolean isEureka(long num) {
        //convert number to string to get length and then sum each digit to the nth power
        //return true or false depending on whether the number qualifies for the list
        String numString = Long.toString(num);
        long sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < numString.length(); i++) {
            sum += Math.pow(Character.getNumericValue(numString.charAt(i)), i+1);
        }

        if(sum == num) {return true;}
        else {return false;}

    }


}
```

expected:<..., 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, []89]> but was:<..., 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ]89]>

Comment: I think the stuff within the brackets is highlighting the difference between the expected result and the actual result. I.e. like it's from a testing package or something.

Comment: It's the output of the one of the asserts on the kata I'm working on on codewars.com

Comment: @ericjb Codewars uses something like JUnit for its tests. I know Algoexpert.io does.

Answer (score 6):

JUnit uses that syntax to show why a test failed, and specifically when an expected String didn't match the actual value:

```
String expected = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 89]";
List<Long> actualLongs = Arrays.asList(
  1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
  1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 89L);
String actualString = actualLongs.toString();
assertEquals(expected, actualString);
```

JUnit figures out the what's similar and different between the expected and actual, and uses the square brackets to highlight that. If you align the "expected" and "but was" bits, you get:

```
expected:<..., 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, []89]>
 but was:<..., 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ]89]>
```

... so it's telling you that in that `[]` space, it expected nothing extra, but found the characters `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,`.

The difference becomes a bit more obvious if it's not just extra characters. For instance, let's say you didn't have the extra values, but the last 89 were instead a 66. Then it would look like:

```
expected:<..., 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, [89]]>
 but was:<..., 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, [66]]>
```

"Where I expected an 89, I found a 66."

I'm not as familiar with TestNG, but it wouldn't surprise me if it does a similar thing.

If you run the test in IDEA IntelliJ, it will even pick up on that syntax and show you a nice diff view of the expected-but-was. Again, I'm not familiar with other IDEs (like Eclipse), but it wouldn't surprise me if they do that as well.